# OnItemClickListener Play Audio In Another Activity

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, onitemclicklistener, android-developer-api

Hello i am trying to learn android studio java programming , i am making simple audio player one list view and one play button , so i need help to audio play in another activity , how to set onitemclicklistener  to play audio in another activity please help me

```
public void doStuff() {

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    getVideo();
    adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

 }
```

//here what is code to write here to play audio in another activity just simple no title show with just play button

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int i, 
        long l) {
        }

    });
}
```

this is my second activity ,,i want to add just one button play only,, i am new so please understand this

```
   public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
   MediaPlayer mp;
   Button bt;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play);


    Intent intent=getIntent();
    int position  = (int) intent.getLongExtra("position", 0);
    if(position!=0){
        //get your song from the position variable 'position' received here
        //and you can start playing your song
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mp.isPlaying()){
                    mp.pause();
                }else {
                    mp.start();
                }
```

Comment: where is mp defined?

Comment: and where is your audio file?

Comment: my audios show from phone memory  in listview on first activity

Comment: then update you full code for your first activity

Comment: So this code not working for me sir ??

Comment: put the whole code for first activity

Comment: Hello sir can you help me how i can make audio player with listview and onitemclick to play audio on another activity with one play , pause button

Answer (score 0):

You can send an intent to your other activity in onItemClick

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int i, 
    long l) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), YouOtherActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("position", i);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

});
```

and in onCreate of your other activity receive the position and play the song

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 .
 .
 .    
 Intent intent=getIntent();
 int postion = intent.getLongExtra("position", 0);
 if(position!=0){
    //get your song from the position variable 'position' received here
   //and you can start playing your song
 }
}
```

Comment: #Shriyansh Gautam    its working on first activity but when i click on item start second but song not playing

Comment: can you show me how you are playing the song in your second activity?

Comment: if this helped you you can accept my answer. We can go for further tutorial in separate question @JagsirSingh